# Node.js send email template ejs use flexbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, nodemailer

I am coding a template and starting to use ejs for mail template. But when I use inline css with ejs its not rendered in mail servers like Gmail. I am new in using ejs so I am highly confused if I use flexbox wrong. Because outputs not related for what I want.

Here's my ejs file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <div style="display: flex; background-color: burlywood; height: 40; width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;"><p>header</p></div>
    <div style="display: flex; background-color: burlywood; height: 200; width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;"><p>bodhy</p></div>
    <div style="display: flex; background-color: burlywood; height: 40; width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;"><p>footer</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my node code.

```
const data = await ejs.renderFile(__dirname + "/simple.ejs", {name: "Name"});

  const mainOptions = {
    from: "my@address",
    to: "to@address",
    subject: "Please activate your account",
    html: data,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mainOptions, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Message sent: " + info.response);
    }
  });
```

Here is the output in Gmail.
[image: screenshot]

I am trying to write a flexbox with different inner proportioned system but ejs file not accept my height or width property. I would like to learn what I am wrong in.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it still helps, but email servers can't recognize flexbox. You will need to internet's year 1 css, such as tables, to align you content